# Hide .php extension in web.config (windows server) running wordpress

Tags: wordpress, windows, web-config

Before anyone makes this a duplicate question please hear me out.  I have researched several ways to do this that should work but I think because wordpress is running on this server it's causing conflict.

The setup: wordpress site running on a windows server.  However, I have files in the webroot outside of the wp-content folder that users need to access.  I need the extension removed on theses files.

When I use this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect .php extension" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="^(.*).php$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).php$" ignoreCase="false" />
    </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="hide .php extension" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" />
    </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It takes the extesion off the urls but the pages outside of wordpress do not work.  I think because of this which is in the web.config already:

```
<rule name="WordPress: http://hiddenwebsitewp.azurewebsites.net" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*"/>
                <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule>
```

Anyone have this problem before?

Comment: Try this https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/remove-file-extensions

Comment: Thanks.  If I were running a linux server this would help me but windows uses a web.config instead of an htaccess .